# Selenium not go to url when open profile firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

options = Options()
options.add_argument("-profile")
options.add_argument("D:/FirefoxData/myprofile")
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities, options=options)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

This code opened to profile named "myprofile", but it do not go to url "http://www.google.com".
When I try to run with no firefox profile, it go to url successful.
Please help me! Thanks!